# Disable url encoding in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, urlencode

One of our partner sites has a webpage with a form where I enter 2-3 number fields, a captcha and then submit the form. It opens a pop-up showing the requested details.

The pop-up url is something like this

```
https://abc.co/xyz/gef/sample/certificate?Values=123456789|2011|A1563894a|y6zs8v|'1373550','4148114'
```

This thing works fine only in IE.

The same process doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox, because the `'` in the url is encoded to something like this

```
https://abc.co/xyz/gef/sample/certificate?Values=123456789|2011|A1563894a|y6zs8v|%271373550%27,%274148114%27
```

I am shown an error

```
We are unable to process your request.  Please try again later or contact Admin for further details. Try Again with Proper Inputs
```

So, basically the server side decoding is set right and as an end user, I am forced to use IE which sucks!

The form action happens is written in Javascript, which I can edit before the post request. Sample code:

```
      var logNo =123456789;
      var url ="/xyz/gef/sample/certificate";
      var fromYear = "2011";
      var logId="A1563894a";
      var textID="y6zs8v";
      var logNoListForCert="'1373550','4148114'";
      var selectedValues =logNo+'|'+fromYear+'|'+logId+'|'+textID+'|'+logNoListForCert;
      window.open('/xyz/gef/sample/certificate?selectedValues='+selectedValues,"Log_Certificate","scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,height=500,left=0, top=0,alwaysRaised=1");
```

So, is there a way I can disable the encoding in Chrome & Firefox or any other workaround for this to work.

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to fix your server to correctly decode the values.

Comment: See the set of reserved characters in a URL: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-12

Comment: Hi,

Neither do I have access to the Server side code nor do the guys there understand my need to use chrome/firefox.